# How to make more than one index in Elastic Search from Kafka connect

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am streaming data from AWS Aurora --> MSK --> Elastic search .
There are 3 columns in records on which i want to create Index in elastic search .
So can this be done in Kafka connect ?
So when kafka connect gets records from Mysql can it put into elastic search and create Index on three columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly use the `query` configuration of the jdbc source to select those three columns

You need separate connectors running to create separate elasticsearch indices, or maybe try using the topic index mapping configuration property